# admob SettingEnabled false

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have a code an i use the same id than an other app that the code i lost. What i can tell you was that this id was working but when i loose the code i can't tell you if with this app the code works or not. What's strange it's that it was working on another app that use admob and facebook mediation. So why it's isn't working with this code i did the same that on the developer admob website

this is my code

```java
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2945227826409900/1799805283");
adView = findViewById(R.id.adView111);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        System.out.print("onAdLoadedAdLoaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
        System.out.print("onAdFailedToLoad");
        System.out.print( errorCode );
    }
});
```

and when i press the button to load an ad:

```java
Bundle extras = new FacebookExtras()
        .setNativeBanner(true)
        .build();

AdRequest request =  new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(FacebookAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();

finalAdView.loadAd(request);
```

the xml code:

```xml
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView111"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2945227826409900/1799805283">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

android manifest:

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-2945227826409900~3138961208"/>
```

I let the id if you need to use them. Thanks for helping. 
 One more detail that can help you
when i execute the code

```
adView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();

                System.out.print("onAdLoadedAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                System.out.print("onAdFailedToLoad");
                System.out.print( errorCode );

            }
        });
```

it print's this error

```
  I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 116 with tag f00d00000000{61453,0} for uid -1, pid: 3713, getuid(): 10198
    bookAdapter: No fill
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
I/System.out: onAdFailedToLoad3(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("4547CA1BE4A487BC5C31C744260B4378") to get test ads on
```

even if one some sit they say that ad failed to load 3 is normal and the code normally works but this time it was working on a app before so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Failed to load ad: 3** there are several reasons for this error

1. Forget to add payment methods on Google AdMod
2. If app is on debugging mode and not in release mode
3. your code is correct but due to less amount of request to the server
   your ads are not Visible
4. forget to enable Contain Ads in google consol

In my case i forget to enable *"Contain Ads"* in google console. you also check in google console

in Google Developer Console there is a section which called "Pricing and Distribution". In this section there is a checkbox "CONTAINS ADS". In our case it was disabled. After enabling we successfully received ads.

Comment: thanks it was because i connect my phone to my computer and bill the app on the computer and now it's working when i do a proper build thanks to have help me